# Several different mouseover font color changes in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, menu

Wait! This isn't just another "how do you change the font color when the mouse hovers over an image/text/etc.?"

I think I can do this as a hack (by inlining the style for each piece of text), **but I've heard that style should be separate from content**. I'm fighting my hacky programmer routes and trying to become more disciplined. So I'm here to ask for the *best* way to do this.

I have a simple menu of links on a website I've made, and I'd like them to be black font (when the mouse isn't hovering over) and then change to a color when the mouse hovers. But I'd like **each to turn a different color when the mouse hovers over it**.

Should I name a style for each of these colors and then declare a `div` when each is used? That seems almost the same as inlining the style.

I'd really appreciate your sage advice on how to *do this the right way!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a { color: black; }
    a:hover { color: grey; }
    a.green:hover { color: green; }
    a.red:hover { color: red; }
    a.blue:hover { color: blue; }
    .content a:hover, .content a.green:hover, .content a.red:hover, .content a.blue:hover { color: yellow; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="green">green link</a>
<a href="#" class="red">red link<a>
<a href="#" class="blue">blue link</a>
<a href="#" >grey link</a>

<div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="green">yellow link</a>
    <a href="#" class="red">yellow link<a>
    <a href="#" class="blue">yellow link</a>
    <a href="#" >yellow link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it all using CSS - just give them different class names and `:hover` states. Swap class names using JavaScript to make different colours after each mouseover event.

html:

```
<a href="..." class="c1">MENU TEXT</a>
```

css:

```
.c1 { background-color:#003300 }
.c1:hover { background-color:#006600 }
.c2 { background-color:#003300 }
.c2:hover { background-color:#006600 }
.....
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm too novice at CSS to know what you mean. Do you mean I should declare several styles with different names (one for each color) and then use div in my content to declare which color is being used?

Comment: You don't need additional DIVs, just use class names on the elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS's nth-child selector, here's an example:

```
#yourMenu ul li:nth-child(1) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
#yourMenu ul li:nth-child(2) {
  color: #00ff00;
}
#yourMenu ul li:nth-child(3) {
  color: #0000ff;
}
...
..
```

Comment: +1 Oooh, I'll have to try it out. I think that looks exactly like what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to give all the different links / `li`s a different class to be able to do this.

The HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="home">Home</li>
  <li class="contact">Contact</li>
  <li class="help">Help</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```
ul.menu li a { color: black; }
ul.menu li.home:hover a { color: #000000; }
ul.menu li.contact:hover a { color: #ffffff; }
ul.menu li.help:hover a { color: #ff3300; }
```

It isn't the best way: the best way would be to use the CSS pseudo-class selector: nth-child.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

However surprise surprise IE doesn't support it. Also older browsers won't support it.

To check out what browsers support it see:

http://caniuse.com/#search=nth

Comment: Ah, I'd rather do it the right/cleanest way (just for pride)! The old world has to die so that the new world can be built on top. Screw IE.

Comment: @Oliver: now we're talking! Too bad my clients don't think like you do :)